# Build angular project with docker and extract dist folder

Tags: angular, docker, docker-volume

I'm using windows pc for work but our company policies doesn't allow build angular project so I'm using docker for it. Now I build angular project inside docker and serve with nginx, it works perfectly. But when any changing in project I have to rebuild docker image, remove existing container and re run container. 
My idea is; I build angular project with docker and send to dist folder to local and i serve dist folder with iis, so when I update my project I only rebuild docker image and remove it after.

Is there any solution for my idea?

Answer (score 1):

Start a container in your build process and use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy content of `dist` folder from running container to local (host) folder. Then you can remove container/image.